# How to install spacewalk on centos 6.8?

Tags: centos, rpm, spacewalk

I am trying to install spacewalk on centos 6.8  with the help of official documentation https://fedorahosted.org/spacewalk/wiki/HowToInstall.

even after adding required repositories i am getting following errors

```
No package spacewalk-setup-postgresql available. 
No package spacewalk-postgresql available.
```

Comment: Do you see the repositories enabled when you run "yum repolist"? Because those packages are in those repo for sure. See http://yum.spacewalkproject.org/2.5/RHEL/6/x86_64/

Comment: No , it was missing there , so i manually copied repo files to /etc/yum.repos.d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by using yum command to install rpm package.

yum install http://yum.spacewalkproject.org/2.5/RHEL/6/x86_64/spacewalk-repo-2.5-3.el6.noarch.rpm